# If $k[X_1,.., X_n]/I$ is a field non algebraic extension of $k$, how to show there exists an algebraically independent subset of $\{X_1+I,..,X_n+I\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $A = k[X_1,.., X_n]/I$ where $k$ is a field and $I$ is some ideal.
Suppose $A$ is a field and $A/k$ is not an algebraic extension. Let $x_i = X_i + I$. I want to show that we can find (relabeling the variables if necessary) there exist $\{ x_1,.., x_r \}$ that is algebraically independent over $k$ and each $x_{r+1},.., x_n$ is algebraic over $k(x_1, .., x_n)$?

Comment: Do you mean $A=k(x_1,...,x_n)$. $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ cannot be a field.

Comment: typo fixed. thank you

Comment: $k[X_1, \dots, X_n]/I$ still can't be a non-algebraic field extension: the quotient by an ideal is a field if and only if the ideal is maximal, but then it would necessarily be an *algebraic* extension of $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Zariski's lemma" states that, for any field $k$, if a field is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra then it is a finite field extension of $k$. Proof of this is below.

However, this means that the circumstances of your problem cannot arise; $A$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra (by the $x_i$), and hence – since it is a field – must be a finite and thus algebraic extension of $k$.

---

Lemma 1: If $E$ and $F=E(x)$ are fields, and $F$ is finitely generated as an $E$-algebra, then $F$ is a finite field extension of $E$.

Proof: Say $F=E[f_1,\ldots,f_n]$, and suppose for contradiction that $F$ is not finite over $E$. Then $x$ must be transcendental over $E$, and so $F$ is the field of rational functions in $x$ over $E$. This means that each $f_i=p_i/q_i$ for some $p_i,q_i\in E[x]$. Consider the element $r:=\frac{1}{x\prod_{i=1}^nq_i+1}\in F$; there must be some polynomial $g\in E[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$ such that $r=g(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$. We can clear denominators in $g(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ by multiplying through with a suitable power of $\prod_{i=1}^nq_i$, giving $s:=(\prod_{i=1}^nq_i)^kg(f_1,\ldots,f_n)\in E[x]$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, and hence $\frac{1}{x\prod_{i=1}^nq_i+1}=\frac{1}{(\prod_{i=1}^nq_i)^k}s$. But this means $(\prod_{i=1}^nq_i)^k=(x\prod_{i=1}^nq_i+1)s$, and this is a contradiction, since $x\prod_{i=1}^nq_i+1$ and $\prod_{i=1}^nq_i$ (and hence $x\prod_{i=1}^nq_i+1$ and $(\prod_{i=1}^nq_i)^k$) are coprime in $E[x]$.

---

Lemma 2: Let $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ rings with $A$ Noetherian. If $C$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra and $C$ is finitely generated as a $B$-module, then $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra.

Proof: See eg [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Tate_lemma).

---

Theorem (Zariski's lemma): Suppose $F:E$ is a field extension and that $F$ is finitely generated as an $E$-algebra. Then $F$ is finite over $E$.

Proof: Say $F=E[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$; we prove by induction on $n$. The case $n=0$ is clear. Now suppose the result holds for $n-1$, and let $E'=E(x_n)\subseteq F$. By the tower law, $[F:E]=[F:E'][E':E]$, and so it suffices to show (i) that $F$ is a finite extension of $E'$ and (ii) that $E'$ is a finite extension of $E$. For (i), note that $F=E'[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}]$, and so – since $E'$ is a field – by the induction hypothesis we have that $F$ is a finite field extension of $E'$. For (ii), note that (i) allows us to apply lemma 2 and show that $E'$ is finitely generated as an $E$-algebra. By lemma 1, this means that $E'=E(x_n)$ is in fact a finite extension of $E$, so (ii) holds and we are done.

Comment: Huh, didn't realize that lemma had a name.

Comment: @DanielHast when I first learned it, my professor always called it the "weak nullstellensatz", so in fact perhaps it even has two names :)

Comment: I'm going through the proof of the mentioned result and I'm trying to understand the first step.

Comment: @TakeshiGouda which proof are you following through? the proof on wikipedia requires familiarity with Noether's normalization lemma, which (based on your previous questions) it looks like you might not be familiar with.

Comment: if you have access to Atiyah-Macdonald's textbook, they give a very accessible proof of this lemma in Proposition 7.9; if you don't have access to the book I can summarize their argument for you on this post

Comment: @TakeshiGouda I have edited the answer to include a proof of Zariski's lemma; let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thank you very much for this answer! I am going through it at the moment. I was in fact trying to understand the proof of Proposition 7.9 in Atiyah-MacDonald. My question, though I used different alphabets, is the first couple sentences in the proof.

Comment: In the proof of Lemma 1 how is $x$ in the definition of $r$ used?

Comment: @TakeshiGouda ah! so the main point is that, if $E(x):E$ is not a finite field extension, then $x$ must not be algebraic over $E$. this means that there are no non-zero polynomials $p\in E[t]$ such that $p(x)=0\in E(x)$. a lot of the elements of $E(x)$ that we are considering in lemma 1 have non-trivial denominators, and if $x$ were algebraic over $E$ there would be no guarantee that these denominators would be non-zero, so those elements wouldn't necessarily be well-defined. however, if $x$ is non-algebraic, we don't have to worry about polynomial expressions in $x$ possibly being zero